# How to wirte an extensible SQL to find the users who continuously login for n days

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

If I have a table(Oracle or MySQL), which stores the date user logins.

So how can I write a SQL(or something else) to find the users who have continuously login for n days.

For example:

```
userID  |  logindate
1000       2014-01-10
1000       2014-01-11
1000       2014-02-01
1000       2014-02-02
1001       2014-02-01
1001       2014-02-02
1001       2014-02-03
1001       2014-02-04
1001       2014-02-05
1002       2014-02-01
1002       2014-02-03
1002       2014-02-05
.....
```

We can see that user 1000 has continually logined for two days in 2014, and user 1001 has continually logined for 5 days. and user 1002 never continuously logins.

The SQL should be extensible , which means I can pick every number of n, and modify a little or pass a new parameter, and the results is as expected.

Thank you!

Comment: Er, what dbms are you using? I've been racking my brain for a MySQL solution. Now I see that you also tagged your question as Oracle (which is much easier, because Oracle has analytic window functions). So: Which dbms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we don't know what dbms you are using (you named both MySQL and Oracle), here are are two solutions, both doing the same: Order the rows and subtract rownumber days from the login date (so if the 6th record is 2014-02-12 and the 7th is 2014-02-13 they both result in 2014-02-06). So we group by user and that groupday and count the days. Then we group by user to find the longest series.

Here is a solution for a dbms with analytic window functions (e.g. Oracle):

```
select userid, max(days)
from
(
  select userid, groupday, count(*) as days
  from
  (
    select
      userid, logindate - row_number() over (partition by userid order by logindate) as groupday
    from mytable
  )
  group by userid, groupday
)
group by userid
--having max(days) >= 3
```

And here is a MySQL query (untested, because I don't have MySQL available):

```
select
  userid, max(days)
from
(
  select
    userid, date_add(logindate, interval -row_number day) as groupday, count(*) as days
  from
  (
    select 
      userid, logindate,
      @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_number
    from mytable
    cross join (select @row_num := 0) r
    order by userid, logindate
  )
  group by userid, groupday
)
group by userid
-- having max(days) >= 3
```

Comment: Thank you! Oracle'version works, and why I add both mysql and Oralce tags is that I hope to get both solutions for this problem in two dbms, thank you! BTW, did you miss `()` on `row_number()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following query will give you a very extensible parametrization:

```
select z.userid, count(*) continuous_login_days 
from
( 
  with max_dates as
  ( -- Get max date for every user ID
    select t.userid, max(t.logindate) max_date
    from test t
    group by t.userid
  ),
  ranks as
  ( -- Get ranks for login dates per user
    select t.*,
           row_number() over
               (partition by t.userid order by t.logindate desc) rnk
    from test t
  )
  -- So here, we select continuous days by checking if rank inside group
  -- (per user ID) matches login date compared to max date
  select r.userid, r.logindate, r.rnk, m.max_date
  from ranks r, max_dates m
  where m.userid = r.userid
    and r.logindate + r.rnk - 1 = m.max_date -- here is the key
) z
-- Then we only group by user ID to get the number of continuous days
group by z.userid
;
```

Here is the result:

```
    USERID  CONTINUOUS_LOGIN_DAYS
1   1000    2
2   1001    5
3   1002    1
```

So you can just choose by querying field `CONTINUOUS_LOGIN_DAYS`.

**EDIT** : If you want to choose from all ranges (not only the last one), my query structure no longer works because it relied on the last range. But here is a workaround:

```
with w as
( -- Parameter
  select 2 nb_cont_days from dual
)
select *
from
(
  select t.*,
         -- Get number of days around
         (select count(*) from test t2
          where t2.userid = t.userid
            and t2.logindate between t.logindate - nb_cont_days + 1
                                 and t.logindate) m1,
         -- Get also number of days more in the past, and in the future
         (select count(*) from test t2
          where t2.userid = t.userid
            and t2.logindate between t.logindate - nb_cont_days
                                 and t.logindate + 1) m2,
         w.nb_cont_days
  from w, test t
) x
-- If these 2 fields match, then we have what we want
where x.m1 = x.nb_cont_days
  and x.m2 = x.nb_cont_days
order by 1, 2
```

You just have to change the parameter in the `WITH` clause, so you can even create a function from this query to call it with this parameter.

Comment: Thank you! I test , it works for the latest login count, what if we want to count in the whole range rather than the latest range.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userID,count(userID) as numOfDays FROM LOGINTABLE WHERE logindate between '2014-01-01' AND '2014-02-28'
GROUP BY userID
```

In this case you can check the login days per user, in a specific period

Comment: This is not continuous... It only gives me the total number of days